# Formik field values arn't being passed from React Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, react-context

I have a Formik form that is using a progressive stepper and have multiple fields across different components, thus requiring the need to store the values in React Context. However none of the field values are being passed, so when I click submit, all values are empty strings and the validation fails. You can see on each Formik Field i am setting the value as {state.[field]}, which comes from the Context, so I believe something is going wrong here. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot

Here is my parent component

```
const AddSongPage = () => {
  const { state, dispatch } = useUploadFormContext();

  const initialValues = {
    name: "",
  };

  const { mutate: handleCreateTrack } = useCreateSyncTrackMutation(
    gqlClient,
    {}
  );

  const handleSubmit = (values: any) => {
    handleCreateTrack(
      {
        ...values,
      },
      {
        onSuccess() {
          console.log("Track added succesfully");
        },
      }
    );
  };

  const validate = Yup.object({
    name: Yup.string().required("Song name is required"),
    description: Yup.string().optional(),
  });

  return (
    <Layout headerBg="brand.blue">
      <Formik
        onSubmit={(values) => handleSubmit(values)}
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={validate}
      >
        <Form>
          <Box> {state.activeStep === 1 && <Step1 />}</Box>
          <Box> {state.activeStep === 2 && <Step2 />}</Box>
          <Box> {state.activeStep === 3 && <Step3 />}</Box>
          <Button type={"submit"}>Submit</Button>
        </Form>
      </Formik>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

Here is step 1

```
const Step1 = () => {
  const { state, dispatch } = useUploadFormContext();
  
  const onInputChange = (e: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const inputName = e.currentTarget.name;
    dispatch({
      type: "SET_UPLOAD_FORM",
      payload: {
        [inputName]: e.currentTarget.value,
      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <Stack spacing={4}>
      <Field name={"name"}>
        {({ field, form }: any) => (
          <FormControl isInvalid={form.errors.name && form.touched.name}>
            <Input
              {...field}
              onChange={onInputChange}
              value={state.name}
            />
          </FormControl>
        )}
      </Field>
      <Field name={"description"}>
        {({ field, form }: any) => (
          <FormControl isInvalid={form.errors.name && form.touched.name}>
            <Input
              {...field}
              onChange={onInputChange}
              value={state.description}
            />
          </FormControl>
        )}
      </Field>
    </Stack>
  );
};

export default Step1;
```